# Import ArcInfo licence when required by tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, arcgis-license-manager

Is it possible to check licences in/out as needed within modelbuilder? or will the following work -write a script to turn arcinfo licence on when the tool requires it and off once it's done?

I need to run a complex model on 100+ segments of data on multiple machines concurrently and we have only one arcinfo licence which is required only by the eliminate tool. Each segment takes about an hour which is approx 100hrs of processing time. We don't have this much time so need to split the process into 6 machines running the arcview licence...the blocker is one-step needing arcinfo. As the machines will need the licence for only 10mins or so at differeing times, I want to get the model to run in arcview upto the eliminate, check-out arcinfo (or if unavailable keep checking every 5 mins), finish the tool and then check-in the info licence so another machine can take it and continue.

Comment: Is your license single-use or a concurrent floating license?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to dedicate a single machine to running the eliminate tool, as you can only run it on one machine at a time anyway.

Comment: It's a concurrent licence so we need to grab the info licence when needed. We can't afford to dedicate a single machine as there are to many zones to process (100+) and so farming them out to all 6 licences cuts the time, since info will only be required at different times (since each machine will get to that step at a certain time).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention using a script, so what about in the script utilizing the [`SetProduct`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003w000000) function? If I understand it properly, you have to explicitly set the product (by importing it) *before* you import the arcpy module:

```
import arcinfo 
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Data"
arcpy.do_whatever_requires_arcinfo
```

Edit: I haven't tested this, but based on your comment below, how about checking for the availability of the ArcInfo license:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.CheckProduct("ArcView")
u'Available'
>>> arcpy.CheckProduct("ArcInfo")
u'Available'
>>> if arcpy.CheckProduct("ArcInfo") == "Available":
...     import arcinfo
...
```

...and then if it's available, `import arcinfo` and do your task. You could perhaps incorporate Python's [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) function to wait until you check again, assuming the license is still tied up.

Comment: Yes this is what I was refering to but it's more complicated than that as it has to set the info licence from within a model running in arcview and if not available continue to the next area but check for the info licence and when available contine processing on the incomplete areas.

Comment: @GeorgeC - see edit

Answer (score 3):

If each process can reset the license manager it can re-signin the arcview license.

The image below shows available concurrent (floating) license.

[image]

Dirty Hack - the license server admin can be 'hacked' to loop the existing license to make more licenses available - but basically this breaks the license agreement.
(google it)

Comment: thanks, how can the process reset the licence manager. Can't do a hack as then I wouldn't be employed anymore :-)

Comment: ArcStorm? That sounds a lot more cool than I am assuming it probably is.

Comment: an old cataloging system - arcstorm

Comment: ArcStorm (Arc Storage Manager) is ESRI’s implementation of Client/Server technology for managing distributed ARC/INFO databases. http://cagis.hamilton-co.org/CAGIS/DataDictionary/asoverview.html

Comment: Definitely not as cool.